# C++ struct initialization with colon ":"

Tags: c++

Within our team's code review I found out a strange usage of struct initialization under C++17 and I'm surprised that it works:

```
struct TestStruct {
  std::string test_str1;
  std::string test_str2;
  std::string test_str3;
};

TestStruct t{test_str1 : "col1", test_str3 : "col3"};
std::cout << "str1: " << t.test_str1 << "\nstr2:" << t.test_str2 << "\nstr3:" << t.test_str3;
```

and here's the result as follow:

```
str1: col1
str2: 
str3: col3
```

I couldn't find references for such usage but it looks like [Constructors and member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) with some ellision.

Can someone explain why it works?
Thanks :)

Comment: [C struct initialization using labels. It works, but how?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1601420)

Comment: Does not compile with my compiler.  Appears to be a GCC extension to **C++**, borrowed from **C**.